# What place is around me

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Hi i wish to develop an app that will notify me important place( say restaurants, shopping mall etc) name.

Lets say i have latitude, longitude( get from GPS ) and radius. With this value i shall pick desired place ( mentioned earlier )from Google maps and shall show this data in a list view .
[image]

In the image...

- green circle denotes my location( latitude, longitude )
- pink rectangle denotes desired place to be pick from Google map
- and a big circle  limit the area around which my desired place will rest on.

Now my question is how to collect this **data**( places name ) that rest inside the big circle.

Below is the image that shows the collected data in a list view.
[image]

**[Sorry for my bad writing]**

Answer (score 2):

> Develop an app that will notify me important place

Have a look at the [Google Places api.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)

> Now my question is how to collect this data( places name ) that rest inside the big circle.

Now this depends on the places you find relevant. [Here is the complete list of supported places](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html)

> big circle limit the area around which my desired place will rest on

You can specify [the search radius](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches) as a parameter.